# Comparing index of a string with character

Tags: string, indexing, compare, ascii

How do we compare an element of an index of a string to a characters?

```
  string a;
  int j;
  for (j = 1; j <= Length(a); j = j + 1)
  if ((a[j] >= ‘t’) && (a[j] <= ‘z’))
      a[j] = a[j] – 32;
  Return(a);
```

}

Do we use ASCII as a part of the solution? and we change characters according to their equivalent ascii after the operation

Comment: What programming language are you using ?
What problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: Some things to keep in mind: This algorithm is highly dependent on 1) the character encoding, which is unstated, but inferred to be ASCII, and 2) the culture/locale, which isn't much of an issue if the character set is ASCII. But, neither is a real-world scenario. Coding tip: even pseudo-code should have comments that state assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing there is taking a single letter and if it is between a lowercase t and z in the *latin* alphabet and converting it to an upper-case (capital) version of itself.

To give a more specific answer you need need to let us know what programming language you are using and what you want to achieve as this is essentially pseudo-code

Edit - okay, yes you are using the ASCII character table (see https://www.asciitable.com/). Each character in the string has a numerical equivalent (as all strings are stored in memory as numbers anyway) and subtracting 32 from the numerical value of the character will convert it to upper-case.

```
Letter 'a' = 97
97 - 32 = 65
65 = 'A'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think your answer is correct. I only have the pseudocode.